# How many white balls at the end of the game?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose there are $N$ balls in an urn, with $X$ white balls and $N-X$ black balls. We perform  $k$ iterations of the following process:

1. Choose a random ball form the urn.
2. If the ball is white, we put it back with an additional white ball and discard a black ball.
3. If the ball is black, we simply put it back.
4. When there are no more black balls, we will always pick white balls. We then return the chosen white ball with an additional white ball as done previously. At this stage, the number of balls increases by $1$ with each iteration.

How many white balls do we have on average, after $k$ iterations?

Comment: Is the description correct? Step $4$ suggests that there may be an iteration in which no black balls are in the urn, whereas step $3$ implies that there will always be black balls...

Comment: @Patricio step 2 removes a black ball, so once we have drawn a white ball $N-X$ times all the black balls will be gone.

Comment: @RossMillikan, my bad, thanks